# how to handle svn properties (externals, executables) to commit into a separate repository

Tags: svn, properties, repository

I am quite new to svn. The following is my problem.

I have the code in the old repository http://old_svn_server/tags/sw_version1, which has the properties such as some external references, executables, etc. I want to create a new repository, let's say http://new_svn_server/user, and put the code there.

How should I work this out in an efficent and right way, like keep using the same externals, keep executables permission, and others (svn:special, etc.)?

I am thinking to use the svn export to get the clean workcopy and commit to the new repository. Then, set the properties one by one. But This is very tedious and error prone.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to `old_svn_server` and `new_svn_server`, you could use [`svnadmin dump`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re31.html) to write out the complete history to a temporary file, transfer that file to the machine of `new_svn_server` and then do an [`svnadmin load`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re36.html) to push the history into `new_svn_server`:

On `old_svn_server`:

```
svnadmin dump /path/to/oldrepo/tags/sw_version1 > dumpfile
```

Then, fetch `dumpfile` and put it on `new_svn_server` and then

```
svnadmin load /path/to/newrepo < dumpfile
```